# Display data from related model in Django admin interface for a model object

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a relationship where a blog post can be assigned any number of tags, and a tag can be associated with any number of blog posts. I'd like to be able to use the Django admin interface to assign tags to posts, and to assign posts to tags.

Right now, to create a blog post and assign any number of tags, here is my model for the posts:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tags", blank=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the model defining the tags:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

This works. I can log into the admin interface and create a bunch of tag objects, then create a post object and assign it any number of those tags.

But let's say I also want to do the opposite. I want to be able to log into the admin interface, select a tag object, and then associate it with any number of post objects.

I tried to do this by defining a `ManyToManyField` in the `Tag` model like so:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField("Post", blank=True, related_name="posts")
```

This does show a list of posts on the change tag page, but I really only want it to show the tags that are associated with that post. And using the admin interface, I'd like to have the ability to select other tags to assign to that post. So I then tried to use a `ForeignKey`, but that will only allow me to select one post.

I know how I can override the default admin `ModelAdmin.change_form_template` with a separate query to display the tags assigned to the posts. But I wasn't sure if there was a way to do this without overriding the default template.

**Edit**: I've revised this question to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I now believe my model is set up correctly. But I was (likely incorrectly) thinking I could add the other field to the second model to make it appear in the admin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this much harder than it needed to be. In order to use the admin interface to assign tags to posts using the models in my question, I just needed to create an `Inline` class:

```
class TagInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Tag.post.through
```

And then specify it in `inlines` under `PostAdmin`:

```
inlines = [TagInline]
```

Now, the relationships appear in the Posts objects in the admin interface.

Thank you to @YongjinJo for getting me on the right track!

Comment: What does `.through` do? I cant find any reference in the documentation?

Comment: From https://www.sankalpjonna.com/learn-django/the-right-way-to-use-a-manytomanyfield-in-django, *"To maintain a many-to-many relationship between two tables in a database, the only way is to have a third table which has references to both of those tables. This table is called a “through” table and each entry in this table will connect the source table (sandwich in this case) and the target table (sauce in this case)."*

Comment: understood. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the related model

Let's say you want to display User email of the address in address model
you can use __ (double underscore )

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user_id', 'user__email', 'user__fullname',
                    'full_name', 'mobile_num', 'pincode',

    # Accessing related table field using foreign key
    def user__email(self, obj):
        # User is related model , email is the field
        return obj.user.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Many to Many field is a field used to define a two-way relationship. However, you seem to be confused in that you have to define only one model when writing it on the django code. See [ManyToMany relationship doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Here are two models.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", related_name='posts')


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

This code will create three table in your database. `posts`, `tags`, and `post_tags`. `post_tags` is intermediary table. It has `id`, `post_id`, `tag_id` fields.

```
p1 = Post.objects.create(title='Post 1')
p2 = Post.objects.create(title='Post 2')
p3 = Post.objects.create(title='Post 3')

t1 = Tag.objects.create(title='Tag 1')
t2 = Tag.objects.create(title='Tag 2')
t3 = Tag.objects.create(title='Tag 3')

p1.tags.add(t1, t2)
p1.tags.all()
>>> [Tag 1, Tag 2]

t1.posts.all()
>>> [Post 1]
t2.posts.add(p2, p3)
t2.posts.all()
>>> [Post 1, Post 2, Post 3]
```

`post_tags` table items:

```
id | post_id | tag_id 
---------------------
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 1
4  | 3       | 1
```

Many to Many field should be defined in only one model, and if defined in the opposite model, duplicate two-way relationships will be created.

And [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) explains how to implement an admin that can select posts from tags page.

Comment: I can't exactly understand what you want. I'd like you to give me a detailed example of which data is displayed on which screen and how it can work. And I also think that a model is a code that expresses the structure of a table in a database, and how it is viewed and how it will be stored through what processing is not the area of the model. If it is a task that requires complex functions or queries, it would be better to override the admin code. @AndroidNoobie